# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom-events, anonymous-function

I'm using fabric.js to draw some text on a canvas. I have a function to create a text label. I'd like to have labels run a function when they're selected. The syntax for this is `label.on('selected', functionToCall());` This works fine when I make the function an anonymous inner function, but when I break it out as a separate function, I get an Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code which doesn't work for me. Here's the [broken code](http://jsfiddle.net/R2mMt/) on jsfiddle, and a version set up with an [anonymous function](http://jsfiddle.net/MUqL5/) which works.

```
"use strict";

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {selection: false}),
  position = 50;

function onLabelSelection(theLabel) {
  if (theLabel.hasOwnProperty('edge')) {
    selectedEdge = theLabel.edge;
  } else {
    selectedEdge = null;
  }
}

function createLabel() {
  var label;
    
  label = new fabric.Text('Hello World', {
    left: position,
    top: position
  });
  position += 50;
    
  label.edge = null;

  label.on('selected', onLabelSelection(this));

  return label;
}

canvas.on('mouse:up', function() {
  var newLabel = createLabel(); 
  canvas.add(newLabel);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The syntax for this is `label.on('selected', functionToCall())`

No. The syntax for event handlers is to *pass* the handler function, not to call it:

```
label.on('selected', functionToCall);
```

You might want to try `label.on('selected', onLabelSelection.bind(this))` or - since `this` inside `createLablel` is apparently `undefined` - just `label.on('selected', onLabelSelection)`.

Comment: Of course. It's always the small things. Thanks for this.

Comment: You're lucky that you have used strict mode :-) Otherwise the `this` that you've passed would've been the `window`, and you wouldn't get an error but just odd behaviour…

Comment: Strict mode is my best friend!